# Are there any Infinite Combos in Monster Train?

Tags: monster-train

In a similar game, [Slay the Spire](https://slay-the-spire.fandom.com/wiki/Infinite_Combo), I know of quite a few infinite combos, however with significantly less "draw" cards in Monster Train, I was wondering if there are any ways to get an infinite combo going?

Most cards draw cards next turn, such as [Sting](https://monster-train.fandom.com/wiki/Sting), so I don't think they can be used,
but maybe an [Awoken Rail Spike](https://monster-train.fandom.com/wiki/Awoken%27s_Rail_Spike) upgraded with Eternalstone can be used for something?

If possible, a nice answer would include combos for both the base game and the Last Divinity DLC.
(My guess is that the -2 cost Valuestone in the DLC would be helpful too...)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here's a fun and surprisingly practical one I just used. With a little luck it's possible to assemble in ring 1.

- 2x Votivary
- 2x Torch (or other single target damage) reduced to 0 cost
- Waxer Snuffer

The rest of the deck needs to be lean enough that no more than 8 cards are in the deck and discard (i.e. everything else is consumed cards or played monsters). This is relatively doable.

To start the combo, you need a votivary in hand or on the train and a torch in hand. The other votivary and torch can be anywhere.

1. Play Votivary
2. Use Torch to kill the Votivary. This means that:
3. You will draw two cards due to Votivary's Extinguish trigger- the other Votivary and other Torch.
4. Votivary will be on the top of your deck due to being Endless. The Torch you cast will be the only card in your discard pile.

You can repeat this as many times as you like and the game state will be the same each time. On its own, this does absolutely nothing.

However, the loop itself involves playing a monster, playing a spell, and a monster dying. It costs nothing and can be played an arbitrary number of times. It triggers:

- Rally
- Incant
- Harvest
- Extinguish (if you infuse an ability into a Votivary)
- Relics that trigger when a unit dies
- Subsuming Blade (if used in place of a torch- if you want you can one shot Seraph with it)

an infinite number of times on any floor(s) with a free pip. Plug this engine into damn near anything and you win.

Answer (score 2):

**Yes**, there are infinite combos in Monster Train.

Here's an illustrative Example of one I remember pulling off at least once, so it's feasible if rare at Covenant 25, and not merely a pathological example:

1. Have your champion be *Little Fade*, give it at least one level of *Fire Light*.
2. Play with the *Stygian Guard* as your secondary clan.
3. Get two copies of *Offering Monument*. (It doesn't need upgrades, but *Quick* can help before the combo pops off completely).
4. Get a copy of the card *Intent on Death* (IOD) from your first combat.
5. Lower its cost down to zero in the first two floors using the Magic shop (or on the first floor using a lucky refresh and cash bonuses from *Collector* and *Challenge*), or using a *Valuestone* if using the DLC.
6. Encounter the event that allows you to copy this card six times (not necessary, but quite helpful in making the infinite easier). *Note: A patch made it so this Event can only be encountered early in the game*.
7. Optional: Find the Artifact *Waxer Snuffer* "Extinguish abilities are triggered twice" for unlimited health as well.
8. Remove as many cards from the deck that aren't *Offering Monument* or *Intent on Death* as possible.

The combo works because each copy played of *Intent on Death* will draw you two cards immediately, allowing you to continue playing them, and ends up giving your monuments unbounded additional attack. As long as you have enough copies in the deck, that is, given your hand size `H`, the number of non-IOD's `X <= 9`, and the number of IODs (I) satisfies `I >= 2, I >= X - H`, then you can draw all your non-IODs in your hand and continue playing *Intent on Death* an arbitrary amount of times on *Little Fade*. Each *Intent on Death* played increases the Attack value of the Monuments, while keeping their health the same (or granting 5 hp if you have the Artifact *Waxer Snuffer*).

Enjoy one-shotting the Seraph with your big monuments of unlimited power.

Answer (score 2):

Here's a nice simple one. Two Deep Offering with consume removed, Kinstone Totem, and a way to consume all but 6 cards of your deck. That leaves room for two deadweights and another card.

Deep offering will, for 3 pyre, give you 4 pyre and redraw a hand of 2 deadweights, Deep Offering, and the other card. You can play Deep Offering as many times as you like.

This gives you infinite energy- if the sixth card is an x cost, you can one-shot bosses with it. It also gives you infinite Incant triggers.

This combo surprisingly practical. Everything is from a single clan and it only requires a relic and two copies of a card. An extremely lucky player can pursue it from the start of the game if they get Deep Offering in their starting deck and Kinstone Totem as their starting artifact.

Note that this combo does not work on Seraph the Chaste on covenant 17+ due to the vengeful shards.

Comment: "Combo does not work against the Chaste's vengeful shards" => Sacrificial resurrection can fix that :)